# Https and http not working together on MAMP Pro

Tags: apache, mamp-pro

I created a host on Mamp pro using their GUI app which is called "site1". If I go to https://site1/, it is working fine. If I go to http://site1, then it loads the root of http://localhost.

Based on GUI,

http//localhost's document root is applications/mamp/htodocs/

http//localhost's document root is applications/mamp/htodocs/site1/

If I disable https, then the http site works correctly. I need the both protocol for the site. How could I fix that? Any help? I am also unable to recognize the correct httpd.conf files which are associated with these hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

On the GUI management window, I just added the following code into the **additional virtual host parameters** and both http and https started working fine together.

```
ServerName site1
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site1"
```

It would still be good to know where and how MAMP is creating the conf files.